# How to prove that if $g*g=0$, then $g=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

Given a continuous function $g$, if the convolution $g*g(t)$ (defined as: $\int^t_0(g(r)g(t−r))dr$ equals $0$, $\forall t\geq 0$, then $g=0$.

My attempt was to use Laplace transformation, but such transformation for the function could be non-existent. I'm also aware of the Titchmarsh theorem, but all the proofs I've found involve material that I hadn't studied yet. The proof for the claim above should neither be very lengthy, nor include material that is studied in Harmonic Analysis.

How can one prove this claim using relatively simple means?

Comment: The best way i think would be to prove the contrapositive statement: if $g \neq 0$ then $ g \ast g \neq 0$. You can use continuity of $g$ to find a ball on which $g>0$ (or $g<0$) from which the result should (hopefully) follow

Comment: @JackT This is exactly one of the methods I was trying to apply here. I assumed that $g$ doesn't equal $0$, and hence has a region that is positive or negative due to continuity, but the integral of the convolution didn't allow me to reach any conclusion. I can't divide the integral in a way that would help me reach a contradiction. If you can elaborate, I'd be thankful.

Comment: It depends what you know about $g$. In general functions must decay sufficiently fast at infinity in order for the convolution to be defined. Assuming that $f,g\in L^1$ is sufficient for their convolution to exist. In this case their Fourier transform is also defined in the usual sense and you can use that approach.

Comment: PS you probably mean $\infty$ as upper integration limit

Comment: @lcv The claim was formulated as I wrote it above. I haven't studied Fourier transform yet, so the proof should go without it. What I know about the function is that it's continuous, nothing else. If only I were given that it has a Laplace transform, I'd have managed. My lecturer said that the proof doesn't need to include Laplace transform, so I believe there should be something fundamental about the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, here's my thought process: Suppose $g\neq 0$ and let $X = \{ t \geqslant 0 \, \vert g(t) \neq 0\}$ which, by assumption, is nonempty. Denote by $t_\ast = \inf X$. Since $g$ is continuous there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $g(\tau) \neq 0$ for all $\tau \in (t_\ast ,t_\ast +\varepsilon)$. Without loss of generality, suppose $g(\tau) > 0$ for all $\tau \in (t_\ast ,t_\ast +\varepsilon)$.

Now consider $(g\ast g)(2t_\ast +\varepsilon)$. Since $g(\tau)=0$ when $\tau \in (0,t_\ast)$, and $g(2t_\ast + \varepsilon-\tau) = 0$ when $\tau \in (\tau_\ast +\varepsilon , 2t_\ast +\varepsilon)$, it follows \begin{align*}
(g\ast g)(2t_\ast +\varepsilon) &= \int_{t_\ast}^{t_\ast+\varepsilon} g(\tau) g(2t_\ast +\varepsilon -\tau) d \tau.
\end{align*} But for $\tau \in (t_\ast,t_\ast+\varepsilon)$, $2t_\ast+\varepsilon-\tau \in (t_\ast , t_\ast + \varepsilon)$, so $g(2t_\ast +\varepsilon -\tau)>0$, so $$(g\ast g)(2t_\ast +\varepsilon)>0.$$

Comment: After posting this question and thinking about it some more I eventually came up with a similar proof. I think I will change my proof a bit, and use more of your formalism regarding the notation $t_* = infX$, since it best describes what I was trying to convey by "...such $t$ that is closest to t=0". Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome. If you’re happy with the answer then I’d appreciate it if you could accept it :)